# conexão php soap wsdl com certificado

Tags: php, soap, certificado-digital, wsdl

Zero de experiência com soap/wsdl e preciso de consumir um web service através de php e soap/wsdl com certificado e chave privada.

Pesquisando, encontrei este código:

```
$local_cert = "../cert.pem";
$local_priv = "../private.key";
$wsdl = "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl";
// editado
$location = "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo";

$options = array(    
    'keep_alive'    => true,
    'trace'         => true,
    'location'      => $location, // editado
    'local_cert'    => $local_cert,
    'local_priv'    => $local_priv,
    'passphrase'    => '1234567',
    'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
);

try {
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Ao conectar, apresenta o seguinte erro:

> object(SoapFault)#2 (9) { ["message":protected]=> string(240)
>   "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl'
>   : failed to load external entity
>   "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl"
>   " ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=>
>   int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(65)
>   "/home/storage/a/7f/23/openselos/public_html/soap/teste/client.php"
>   ["line":protected]=> int(50) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(1)
>   { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(65)
>   "/home/storage/a/7f/23/openselos/public_html/soap/teste/client.php"
>   ["line"]=> int(50) ["function"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" ["class"]=>
>   string(10) "SoapClient" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(2)
>   { [0]=> string(78)
>   "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl"
>   [1]=> array(6) { ["keep_alive"]=> bool(true) ["trace"]=> bool(true)
>   ["local_cert"]=> string(11) "../cert.pem" ["local_priv"]=> string(14)
>   "../private.key" ["passphrase"]=> string(7) "1234567" ["cache_wsdl"]=>
>   int(0) } } } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL
>   ["faultstring"]=> string(240) "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load
>   from
>   'https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl'
>   : failed to load external entity
>   "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl"
>   " ["faultcode"]=> string(4) "WSDL" }

Erro após o editado:

> object(SoapFault)#2 (9) { ["message":protected]=> string(240)
>   "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl'
>   : failed to load external entity
>   "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl"
>   " ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=>
>   int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(65)
>   "/home/storage/a/7f/23/openselos/public_html/soap/teste/client.php"
>   ["line":protected]=> int(52) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(1)
>   { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(65)
>   "/home/storage/a/7f/23/openselos/public_html/soap/teste/client.php"
>   ["line"]=> int(52) ["function"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" ["class"]=>
>   string(10) "SoapClient" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(2)
>   { [0]=> string(78)
>   "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl"
>   [1]=> array(7) { ["keep_alive"]=> bool(true) ["trace"]=> bool(true)
>   ["location"]=> string(73)
>   "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo"
>   ["local_cert"]=> string(11) "../cert.pem" ["local_priv"]=> string(14)
>   "../private.key" ["passphrase"]=> string(7) "1234567"
>   ["cache_wsdl"]=> int(0) } } } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=>
>   NULL ["faultstring"]=> string(240) "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't
>   load from
>   'https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl'
>   : failed to load external entity
>   "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl"
>   " ["faultcode"]=> string(4) "WSDL" }

O certificado usado anteriormente estava com algum tipo de problema, pois deu erro no SoapUI e após usar outro certificado, tudo funcionou.
Este novo certificado, foi convertido para .pem com chave privada incluída, mas mesmo assim continua com erro.

```
// link wsdl
$wsdl = "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl";

// certificado
$cert = "Opensystem_A1.pem";
$cert_senha = 'senha';

$param = array(    
     'keep_alive'    => true,
     'trace'         => true,
     'local_cert'    => $cert,
     'passphrase'    => $cert_senha,
     'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
);

try {
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $param);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

O erro:

> object(SoapFault)#3 (9) { ["message":protected]=> string(240)
>   "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl'
>   : failed to load external entity
>   "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl"
>   " ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=>
>   int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(65)
>   "/home/storage/a/7f/23/openselos/public_html/soap/teste/client.php"
>   ["line":protected]=> int(52) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(1)
>   { [0]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(65)
>   "/home/storage/a/7f/23/openselos/public_html/soap/teste/client.php"
>   ["line"]=> int(52) ["function"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" ["class"]=>
>   string(10) "SoapClient" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(2)
>   { [0]=> string(78)
>   "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl"
>   [1]=> array(5) { ["keep_alive"]=> bool(true) ["trace"]=> bool(true)
>   ["local_cert"]=> string(17) "Opensystem_A1.pem" ["passphrase"]=>
>   string(5) "senha" ["cache_wsdl"]=> int(0) } } } }
>   ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL ["faultstring"]=> string(240)
>   "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl'
>   : failed to load external entity
>   "https://selodigital.tjce.jus.br/wsselodigital-homologacao/SolicitacaoSelo?wsdl"
>   " ["faultcode"]=> string(4) "WSDL" }

Comment: O certificado e a chave são acessíveis com o caminho que você colocou (.../cert.pem ../private.key)? A senha  está correta?

Comment: @Marabesi, sim, tudo ok, caminho, senha. :/

Comment: Talvez esse link possa te ajudar https://stackoverflow.com/a/11681353/2258921

Comment: Mas nessa conexão só tem o certificado, não tem chave privada...

Comment: Você já tentou mandar o conteúdo da chave privada em vez do caminho do arquivo? Pode ser com file_get_contents para testar

Comment: Fui verificar a senha e verifiquei que estava incorreta... no entanto, continua com o mesmo erro. Adicionei o 'location' e o conteúdo da chave com file_get_contents e continua com o erro, acrescentei acima.

Comment: Aparentemente o certificado estava com algum tipo de problema. Testei no SoapUI, e deu erro. Contatei o suporte do serviço que recomendaram usar outro certificado e não deu erro, funcionou direitinho, no entanto, no script de php continua com erro. Editei a pergunta com o novo certificado (só .pem com chave incluída) e erro.